# Is it conventional to place a piecewise function directly in front of a sigma function?

Tags: notation

$$x = \sum_{k=1}^n \begin{cases} a & k \le y \\ b & k > y \end{cases} \tag1$$

$$x = \sum_{k=1}^n \biggr( s =\begin{cases} a & k \le y \\ b & k > y \end{cases} \biggr) \tag2$$

Which is correct notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notations both seem quite unconventional. I would probably suggest just defining

$$a_k = \begin{cases}
a, & k\leq y, \\
b, & k>y
\end{cases},$$

and then just writing

$$x=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k,$$

or maybe doing something like

$$x=\sum_{k=1}^{\min\{y,n\}} a +\sum_{k=y+1}^n b.$$

I'd probably recommend the first one though.

Comment: Thanks. I thought one of those options would've been conventional. Seems like a quick way to express the idea, without having to preface the expression with a definition.

Answer (score 6):

I don‘t like either. I‘d write: For $1\le k\le n$ let $$ s_k = \begin{cases} a & k\le y\\ b& k> y\end{cases}$$ and $$ x = \sum_{k=1}^n s_k.$$

Answer (score 1):

Close to Lorago’s second version, there’s also
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a1_{\{k\le y\}}(k)+ b 1_{\{k> y\}}(k),
$$
which may be convenient in some situations. Here, the $1$’s are indicator functions, which there are many notations for, some more compact than what I wrote. E.g. Iverson brackets.